# How to remove ads present within a link in java

Tags: java, android

I am requesting an url `https://openload.co/embed/igJtWFnw8Jk/`
from android which is consisting of ads this link automatically redirects to an ad page but not getting the original link.I have searched it every where but no help.can anyone give me a solution for this kind of problem

Comment: How are you requesting the url?  In an webview?  A browser?  An http connection?  THere's not enough detail to answer your question.

Comment: Can't replicate - mine takes me to the site

Answer (score 0):

That redirecting is not up to you. I guess it is implemented on the server side (PHP etc.), so that you have no influence on that. It is supposed to behave that way.
I guess the only thing you can do is to get the redirected address and block the redirecting, as soon as the address changes.